# Jordan normal form for a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, jordan-normal-form

The following is a question from an old exam:

> Let $P_n$ be the vector space of polynomials of degree less than or equal to $n$ with complex coefficients. Define $L:P_n \to P_n$ by $$L(p(x))=p(x+1)-2p(x)+p(x-1)$$ for all $p \in P_n$. Show that $L$ is nilpotent, and determine the Jordan normal form of $L$.

My attempt:

Showing that it is nilpotent is easy (the operator lowers the degree of the polynimal by two). Since it is nilpotent, the only eigenvalue is zero. But I don't know how to determine the Jordan normalform of L. I have looked at what happens with the basis vectors, and L obvisouly sends them lower degree polynimal, which makes L upper triangular. But, I don't know how to proceed from there.

Comment: Start with $n=1, 2, 3$. What happens?

Comment: What’s $\dim\ker L$? What does that say about the number of blocks? What’s the minimal polynomial of $L$? What does that say about the largest block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you’ve noted, $L$ reduces the degree of the polynomial by two, so its kernel consists of polynomials of degree less than two. As the only eigenvalue is $0$, for $n\ge2$ this implies that there will be two blocks in the JNF. The minimal polynomial of $L$ is $x^k$, with $k=\lfloor n/2\rfloor+1$ (verify this!). This gives you the size of the largest Jordan block.

Comment: Thanks for the help. A couple of questions:How do you know that there will only be two jordan blocks? The minimal polynomial is, I guess, for even degrees? (so that it will be (n+1)/2 for odd degrees?)

Comment: @user5744148 The kernel is two-dimensional, so there can be at most two Jordan chains. The minimal polynomial that I have in the answer is correct for both even and odd $n$: note the “floor” brackets.

Answer (score 2):

I'll handle the case where $n$ is even, but the case where $n$ is odd is similar.

You have correctly found that for any $p \in P_n$, $\deg(L(p)) = \deg(p) - 2$.  We also find that $\ker(L) = \operatorname{span}(\{1,x\}) = P_1 \subset P_n$.  We can deduce that
$$
\dim \ker(L^k) = \begin{cases}
2k & k \leq n/2\\
n & k > n/2
\end{cases}
$$
Thus, we find that
$$
\dim \ker L^k - \dim \ker L^{k-1} = 
\begin{cases}
2 & k \leq n/2\\
1 & k = n/2\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Now, note that $\dim \ker L^k - \dim \ker L^{k-1}$ is the number of Jordan blocks (associated with $\lambda = 0$) whose size is at least $k$ (where we define $L^0 = I$).

We deduce that the Jordan form of $L$ is $J_{n/2} \oplus J_{1+n/2}$, where $J_k$ denotes the Jordan block associated with $\lambda = 0$ of size $k$.

Comment: Is there something missing in the cases (right hand side) for $dim(ker(L^k)-dim(ker(L^{k-1})...$ line?

Comment: Yes, see my latest edit.

Comment: If $n$ is odd, then you obtain $J_{(n+1)/2}\oplus J_{(n+1)/2}$ ($dim(P_n)=n+1$).

Comment: @loup fixed it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

We can also reason as follows.

Let $f:p(x)\mapsto p(x+1/2)-p(x-1/2)$; then $L=f\circ f$. Moreover $dim(\ker(f^k))-dim(\ker(f^{k-1}))=1$ or $0$ and the Jordan form of $f$ is $J_{n+1}$.

Finally, the Jordan form of $L$ is the Jordan form of ${J_{n+1}}^2$, that is, the one described by Omnomnomnom .